# BEAUti not accepting taxa tip dates

Tags: multiple-sequence-alignment, beast

I'm using [BEAUti](https://beast.community/tip_dates) as part of my pipeline and the sequence names include `|` to separate the metadata fields - with culture date being at the very end.

When I attempt to auto-configure the tip dates on the sequences however, some of the sequences will not update their date(raw value) and if I double-click and manually change the date it will then reverse back to 0.

Any idea what may be preventing me from manually correcting the dates or auto-config to ignore the culture date after the last `|`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, one of my Seq IDs had a `,` in one of the meta-data fields, this appears to have thrown off the software and all subsequent Seq IDs could not be auto-configured.

Simply removing the `,` solved the issue.